# Workbench para PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Alguém sabe de algum Workbench para o PostgreSQL? Estou precisando, pois não quero mexerno postgres por linha de comando.

Comment: Sim existem algumas opções.

Comment: qual a melhor opção?

Answer (score 10):

Existem algumas opções de gerenciadores gráficos:

Livres:

- [PHPpgAdmin](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php)
- [PgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/)

Pagas:

- [Postgres Enterprise Manager](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products/postgres-enterprise-manager)

[Aqui tem uma lista outras ferramentas](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools).

Comment: Esse é muito bom [PgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/), valew pela sugestão...

Answer (score 7):

O Novissimo DataGrip da JetBrains , PAGA. 30 dias free para testar e se apaixonar.
Se já estiver escrevendo codigo em algum IDE da plataforma iDEA da jetbrains vai ficar em casa.
https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/

Comment: +1 Desconhecia essa nova ferramente da JetBrains.

Comment: Um detalhe: essa ferramenta já está embutida na maioria das IDEs da JetBrains, não precisa instalar/comprar o DataGrip standalone. Basta ir em View > Tools Windows > Database

Comment: apenas em versoes 'professional' nas versoes 'comunity' nao está disponivel

Answer (score 3):

Se for pra fazer modelagem de banco (MER) tem o pgModeler.

http://pgmodeler.com.br/

Comment: É free ou paga?

Comment: Tem as duas versões, mas se vc não conseguir baixar no site deles procura em outro site pra baixar. Ele é muito, vale a pena utilizar.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo linux e usava o navicat com o wine... Porém dava erros constantes de consulta, onde era necessário abrir e fechar o programa. Hoje um colega me indicou o [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/download/) e estou gostando MUITO!

Além da versão desktop, existe um plugin para o eclipse onde vc consegue executa-lo por lá! :D